# Record webcam video along to music

Tags: windows, video, music, video-editing

I was wondering if there are any video editors available for Windows 7 that allow one to play an audio track while recording so the two stay in sync. Syncing by hand is a nightmare, and while I am familiar with both Windows Movie Maker and Premiere Pro CC 2014, neither are able to do this. WMM requires video before adding music, and Premiere Pro can't record from a webcam!

Answer (score 1):

It's the sort of feature VirtualDub would have. I have no way to test this, however :(

http://www.virtualdub.org/

If not directly, you can probably trick it into having it through plugins and filters. If you can get it to pass the audio through ffdshow you can use avisynth support to replace the audio.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in other answers before, [PotPlayer](https://potplayer.daum.net/) is very versatile in this regard, and should cater to your need.

In particular, here's a quick how-to to get you started easily:

- Press "CTRL-D" to open the device settings (or alternatively do "Right click, open, device settings") and select the "Webcam" tab
- Choose your audio input device. By default, it's probably set to your microphone, but as you can see you can chose any device, including your main audio card (you might have to try a few before you find the correct one, but if you see "Stereo Input" or something like that it should be that one)
- Disable the "preview audio" checkbox, or you risk getting a feedback loop through your speakers
- Click "open device"

At this point, you should see a preview of your webcam. To start recording video simply press "ALT-C" (or alternatively do "Right click, Video, Video Recording, Record video...")

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Adobe Presenter Video Express](http://www.adobe.com/products/presenter-video-express.html). It records your screen along with your webcam. You can put the music on your computer and select your  integrated microphone. Both your music and whatever you are saying will get recorded at the same.